# Header Issues On Wordpress Installation

Tags: wordpress, error, cron-job, cron

I am getting the following errors when doing various tasks in and around CiviCRM only

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at .../public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php:1) in .../public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Base.php on line 912
```

When hitting save on things like clearing cache and updating paths. If I just hit refresh the page loads right up, but won't on the original button press.

and

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at .../public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php:1) in .../public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Session.php on line 127
```

When running cron jobs. I know these are probably related, but would really love to get them fixed as the last one is blocking cron from running via url.

Wordpress Version: 4.7.4
CiviCRM Version: 4.7.19

Comment: Any other plugins installed? Does it go away if you deactivate CiviCRM?

Comment: It only comes up IN CiviCRM when I execute stuff. Like hitting Print on a Report button or running the Cron Job or the two outlined above. The pages only display those errors. 

I do have other plugins activated. I suppose I can try that.

Comment: Deactivated all Wordpress Plugins, same thing. I'll check the 3 remaining extensions that I did not deactivate earlier

Comment: Disabled all extensions also and no change.

Comment: The warnings suggest that you look at the `wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php` file to see if it's got whitespace at the top of it for some reason. Have you looked there?

Comment: I did look at the file and saw no whitespaces. I even reuploaded the file from the most recent download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure WHAT was different, but I just went back and reloaded the System.php file again, and it is working now.

Comment: I currently have a similar issue and I am also running on Wordpress: (Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at .../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Task.php:132) in .../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Base.php on line 926). This occurs when searching for event participants in the Events menu. When you say you reloaded the System.php again, what do you mean by "reloaded"?